# Robots.txt allow URL if it ends with something

Tags: robots.txt

I have user created URLs which all end with `/post`. I want to be able to for search engines to crawl those URLs. I have disallowed all other URLs. Here are some examples:

```
www.website.com/john-smith/my-blog/post
www.website.com/jim-thomas/my-skiing-blog/post
www.website.com/matt-jones/blog-about-gaming/post
```

How would I do this? Thanks.

Comment: By default, crawling of everything is allowed. Do you *block* (`Disallow`) something? -- Also note that robots.txt is about crawling, not indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually very simple:

```
Allow: /post$
```